# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**hello I'm trying to do a FOR loop in oracle but it throws the following error

ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:
   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
    <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol ";" was substituted for "FOR" to continue.**

```
DECLARE
PROV number;
RAN_PRICE NUMBER;

begin
prov := 1
for loop_one in 1..10 
loop

FOR LOOP_two IN 1..5   
LOOP

SELECT (1+ABS(MOD(dbms_random.random,1800)))into RAN_PRICE FROM dual;
INSERT INTO marcos.PRODUCTO
VALUES(SEQ_PRODUCTO.nextval, 'Producto_'||PROV,RAN_PRICE,PROV);
END LOOP ;

PROV := PROV+ 1;
end loop ;

commit; 
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Se ha producido un error') ;
rollback;               
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of `prov`'s initialization:

```
prov := 1;
-- Here -^
```

Comment: it was that; thanks and sorry for the stupid question